# How to design a buck converter with feedback?

Tags: buck, feedback

I design a simple circuit activates fan when processor heats up and then control rotation speed. I got the idea to create a buck-mode step-down voltage converter. However, I would like stabilize output voltage of the converter.

But I can't interfere in the PCB with microcontroller and I have only +5V, GND and PWM pins.

[image]

Do you have any idea on how to do that?

Comment: hm, not quite sure that if you charge your inductor through the load it's still called a buck converter

Comment: Are you wanting to make a differential measurement of the voltage across the fan (can't be single-ended as it is floating up above ground like a balloon) and control the FET on the basis keeping that within some range of values? Or do I misunderstand?

Comment: @MarcusMüller it looks the same as every other buck converter to me, except that this one uses a low-side switch.  Flip it upside-down and see if it looks more familiar.

Comment: measuring the voltage at the bottom of C1 will give some indication of how fast the fan should be spinning, less difference from VDD means slower speed. using a speed signal from the fan is made harder because this signal is referenced to the negative terminal of the fan motor, and that voltage isn't fixed.

Comment: @Jasen fair point!